# I need help to convert date and time to solo date

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have just started using the C# language in Visual Studio for a course related to database management, I am following along with the teacher, in which the course is being taught remotely. I am to present a final project.

1. I am using asp .net with two .net core libraries, added sqlserver, in which the first library (Selfish.Entidades) declare 1 class of each table, and then in the second library (Selfish.Datos) I do the mapping between the entity class of each table with its respective table and another class I make use of the DbContext, then in the asp .net core, I make use of the cruds for each table, without using sql server statements like "select * from" among others, I only call to show data from each table inside the "Controller" folder of asp .net to display data.
2. I have a problem that when showing data from a specific table that in this case is "document_payment" there is a field of type date and at the time of programming in c # there is only datetime and at the time I use its raw to show data it shows me date and time. I just want to be shown the date nothing else, I want to find out where to put the encoding to show me only the date.

-DATABASE AND TABLES

[image]

-I encoded the "Datatype" and the "DisplayFormat" but the date still appears to me, below you will see the result
[image]
-In this class it belongs to the library (Selfish.Datos) and in this library I do the mapping and the dbcontext
[image]
-Dbcontext part 1
[image]
-Dbcontext part 2
[image]
-Here I make the class for the crud show called "DocumentoPagoViewModel" from asp.net and then call it in the folder "Controllers"
[image]
-Controller that calls the crud to show data through the link "api / DocumentoPagoes / Listar"
[image]
-Result :c
[image]

I am new to C#, I am just getting started in programming.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the solo date thing use `DateTime.Date` [Here have a look on Microsoft documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Where would you place it?